# Branch project not need type password in Bazaar

Tags: php, bazaar

In server1, I branch 1 project version control which belong to server2. The command like:

```
$ bzr branch "sftp://[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]@[HOST]/PATH/OF/PROJECT"
```

The command execute and require password to execute continue (although I have already put PASSWORD in command):

```
[USERNAME]@[HOST]'s password: <I type PASSWORD of USERNAME in here to continue>
Branched 2 revision(s).
```

The command execute successfully. But I don't want to type PASSWORD, because I will execute this command in PHP and I don't know how to type PASSWORD when command execute.

Are there any way/idea to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Belongs in serverfault.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure that in [~/.bazaar/authentication.conf](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/developers/authentication-ring.html#use-cases).